# Does this modified Rieman Sum converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Assume $f \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is continuous and bounded. Further take the sequence $(q_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\{ q_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1].$

Does then $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(q_i) = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx $$ hold?

Comment: Not generally. It holds when $(q_i)$ is an _equidistributed_ sequence, most enumerations of the rationals aren't equidistributed.

Comment: @DanielFischer does an equidistributed sequence of rationals exist? If so, how would you construct it?

Comment: I think one can enumerate $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ by an equidistributed sequence. I don't know how I would construct one, though. Maybe listing the rationals in increasing order of their denominators (in reduced form) works [numbers with the same denominator perhaps in increasing order, perhaps (pseudo-)randomly]. I'll be bold and say I expect that would work.